# How can I limit my user input through a HTML form of 5 characters, starts with an uppercase S and is followed with four numbers?

Tags: php, html, regex

I've been stuck with this regex problem for my assignment. I can't get the right pattern to check the user's input if it starts with an uppercase 'S' and it has to be followed by four integers.

My current code looks like this:

input type="text" name="statuscode" id="statuscode" maxlenght="5" pattern="/^S[0-9]{4}$/"/>

Really need to get my head around this >:(

Comment: sorry, i have my code there but it doesnt show once i posted it?

Comment: I fixed my post above you should be able to see it now

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need:

```
<?php
    $a = 's1234';
    $b = 'S2345';
    $c = 'S234A';

    function checkthe($pattern) {
        if($pattern[0] !== 'S') { return 'Failed'; }
        elseif (!ctype_digit(substr($pattern, 1, 4))) { return 'Failed'; }
        else { return 'Success'; }
    }

    echo checkthe($a) . "<br />\n";
    echo checkthe($b) . "<br />\n";
    echo checkthe($c) . "<br />\n";
?>
```

If you need Regex:

```
<?php

$regex = '/S{1}\d\d\d\d/m';
$str = 'S1234
s4224
S2222
';

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);


?>
```

OR:

```
<input type="text" name="statuscode" id="statuscode" minlenght="5" maxlenght="5" pattern="/S{1}\d\d\d\d/m"/>
```

Test here:  https://regex101.com/r/B4sDGw/1

Comment: I have edited my post above, can you please judge it thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested the function above and it works as well! Now to decide which one to use :)

Comment: @ozoneburger you are most welcome. If it solves te issue then please mark this question as solved.